# Creating menu logic with Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to dynamically create a menu using basic logic, something like this.

- List item

  - List item
- List item

  - List item
  - List item

I made this code

```
<ul>
    <div data-th-each="field, iter : ${fields}" data-th-remove="tag">
        <div data-th-if="${field.text} != null" data-th-switch="${field.href}" data-th-remove="tag">
            <li data-th-case="null" data-th-utext="${field.text}" >
            <li data-th-case="*"><a data-th-href="${field.href}" data-th-utext="${field.text}" ></a>
        </div>
                <ul data-th-if="${field}"  class="sub-menu">
                    <div data-th-each="prop, propIter : ${field.sub_items.sub_item.properties}" data-th-remove="tag">
                        <div data-th-if="${prop.text} != null" data-th-switch="${prop.href}" data-th-remove="tag">
                            <li data-th-case="null" data-th-utext="${prop.text}"></li>
                            <li data-th-case="*"><a data-th-href="${prop.href}" data-th-utext="${prop.text}"></a></li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
          </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

But it returns parsing errors, I think it's mostly a Thymeleaf/HTML problem.
It's probably because of the unclosed "li" tags in the switch statement but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it has to be valid html before processing.  You can't do any kind of tricks like you have above, even if the output would be valid html.

I think you should be able to restructure your html to look like this:

```
<ul>
    <th:block data-th-each="field, iter : ${fields}" data-th-if="${field.text} != null">
        <li>
            <span data-th-if="${field.href == null}" data-th-utext="${field.text}" />
            <a data-th-unless="${field.href == null}" data-th-href="${field.href}" data-th-utext="${field.text}" />

            <ul data-th-if="${field}" class="sub-menu">
                <th:block data-th-each="prop, propIter : ${field.sub_items.sub_item.properties}" data-th-if="${prop.text} != null">
                    <span data-th-if="${prop.href == null}" data-th-utext="${prop.text}" />
                    <a data-th-unless="${prop.href == null}" data-th-href="${prop.href}" data-th-utext="${prop.text}" />
                </th:block>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </th:block>
</ul>
```

I've never though about using `data-th-remove="tag"` like you have.  But I think you should be using `<th:block>` instead for cases like this.